# Отключение обработки события

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть событие **pictureBox1_MouseWheel**. И мне нужно отключать его при запуске формы и включать по нажатию на кнопку, есть ли простой способ это сделать? (желательно без булевых операций).

Comment: так не подписывайтесь на событие когда вам оно не нужно и подписывайтесь когда нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите подписываение на событие из дизайнера, и подписывайтесь и отписывайтесь в коде.

Подписаться

```cs
pictureBox1.MouseWheel += pictureBox1_MouseWheel;
```

Отписаться

```cs
pictureBox1.MouseWheel -= pictureBox1_MouseWheel;
```

Только контроллируйте, чтобы не было подписываний, когда уже подписаны и наоборот, иначе это может привести либо к нескольким одновременным срабатываниям обработчика, либо к другим ошибкам.